# IIS7.5 and Team Foundation Server - redirect to tfs.domain.com

Tags: iis-7.5, team-foundation-server

We'd like a convenient path for users to access TFS: http://tfs.company.com/.

We made a new entry in DNS, then created a new IP on the machine, and then set up a binding to the Team Foundation Server IIS web site to the new IP.  This works okay, but in order to access tfs we have to go to http://tfs.company.com/tfs/.

I'd like to remove the extra "tfs" at the end, but can't seem to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the virtual directory in TFS is a configurable option. If you're up for it, maybe try reinstalling TFS, but this time don't use the v-dir. Then map the DNS name to the new server.

Comment: I prefer to setup a redirect to the vDir and leave it there to stick with convention because there may be other tools or services that hit it that way;  also, when users search online for how to connect, etc... following the conventional approach will make it more clear to them about what to do;  if the vDir isn't there it might confuse people.

Answer (score 3):

do a redirect from the root of the site to /tfs.  You can do this in IIS pretty easily.  If a user hits it on http://tfs.company.com/ , their browser will redirect to the sub application /tfs without having to do anything.  Remember to use SSL on the internets :) if this is going to be a public web site.  If it's internal, no worries.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the first thing I tried, setting up an HTTP Redirect for that site to the sub folder. But something strange happened when I tested it. Instead of working properly it forwarded to ww35.tfs.compnay.com. "company" was misspelled and  ww35 was prepended. I triple checked that I didn't make any misspellings in the redirect. I am assuming that our IT Director has some mistake in a DNS entry somewhere but I don't know where to tell him to look.

Comment: Sounds like you may be in a server farm or something like that.  That behaviour you describe is not normal - so yeah - your IT director will need to take a look - sounds like they have something screwed up internally.